# Is '明天你都六点起床不起床？' a correct question?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

I want to ask: Will you wake at 6:00 tomorrow?

Comment: If you mean `Do you plan to wake up at 6:00 tomorrow?`, then it should be `明天你要六点起床吗？`

Comment: The English question itself sounds very awkward. If you want to signal future intention, then use the present continuous tense: Are you planning/going to wake up at six tomorrow?, to which the answer would be YES. However, if you asked me: will you....? My answer would be I DON'T KNOW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"明天你都六点起床不起床？" is not a valid sentence in Chinese.

If we remove 都, and make it "明天你六点起床不起床？", it is valid but a little awkward. Because we **usually** don't say things like "起床不起床?", "吃饭不吃饭?", "睡觉不睡觉?", "学习不学习?" etc. when asking questions. The point here is that we **normally** don't repeat the whole word before and after 不 in questions, instead we simplify it.

Note: It is ok to repeat the whole word before and after 不 in declarative statements, like 老师喜欢不喜欢你，我真的觉得不是什么问题. While it can also been simpified as 老师喜不喜欢你，我真的觉得不是什么问题.

Here is the natual way to say it in Chinese:

> 起床不? or 起不起床?
>
> 吃饭不? or 吃不吃饭不?
>
> 睡觉不? or 睡不睡觉?
>
> 学习不? or 学不学习?

Back to your question, "明天你都六点起床不起床？" is not correct.

If you are asking a person of his/her get-up time in the moring, you would say:

> 你早上6点起床嘛? or 你早上6点起来嘛?

If the listener usually gets up at 7 o'clock, and you want to know if that person plans to get up at 6 o'clock tommorow morning, then you can say:

> 明早你六点起床不? or 你明天早上六点起来吗?

Answer (score 2):

你会明天早上六点起床吗？ (Will you wake up at 6am tomorrow?)

If I were to salvage your question so it at least makes sense, it'd be:

明天六点,你起床不起床？ (Tomorrow at 6am, will you wake up or not?)